# Rewrite rules in hhvm to use pretty urls on specific project applications only

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, hhvm

### Enviroment

Using HHVM 3.0 in Ubuntu Saucy 13.10, with Apache2 and using Fastcgi

### Overview

I have installed the aforementioned applications and have configured as seen in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/joeyhipolito/9889463)

By default apache uses `/var/www` as the root directory of all my projects and accessing:

```
0.0.0.0/project1
```

would give me as I expected (That is reading the `index.php` as the default document).

### The problem

The problem then arises when I want to use **pretty urls** for an application, because I can no longer use `.htaccess` to do url rewrites and serve all request to `index.php`

### What I did

Okay what I did is to look for solution over the internet and found several configurations for `VirtualHost` directive like so:

```
VirtualHost {
  * {
    Pattern = .*
    RewriteRules {
      * {
        pattern = (.*)$
        to = index.php/$1
        qsa = true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And what I presume it do is to have pretty urls work on the SourceRoot as defined in the Server directive or I am wrong?

### Question

How do I make pretty urls on projects only that I need it to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at `RewriteRule` in apache. You want apache to be doing the rewrites. All HHVM does is serve whatever file apache tells it to.

Comment: I had a talk in hhvm channel, told me to do it in the vhosts.